# Получение номера телефона со страницы

Tags: php

Задача: получить номер со страницы яндекс недвижимости.
номер скрыт и при нажатии отправляется `POST`-запрос с параметрами `crc` и  `offerId`. Я отправляю точно такие же, но в ответ ничего не приходит.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://realty.yandex.ru/offer/3107720");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,           $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    preg_match('/crc&quot;:&quot;(.*?)&quot;/i', $output, $a_crc);
    $crc=$a_crc[1];

    $ch = curl_init();
    $url="https://realty.yandex.ru/gate/phone/count";
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "params[offerId]=3107720&crc=$crc");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');
     $response = curl_exec($ch);
     var_dump($response);
     curl_close($ch);
```

в `$response` пусто...

Comment: Ну как минимум у вас тут нет заголовков Referer и User-agent передается непонятно какой. Яндекс вполне кроме кук может убеждаться в правильном реферере и убеждаться, что браузер тот же самый. По крайней мере я бы на их месте выполнял такие проверки

Comment: пробовал и юзер-агентом и реферрером. var_dump(response) выдает true

Comment: Заглянул я в куки на этом realty ... жуть. там вполне могут быть какие то куки привязанные к IP-адресу пришедшего. Плюс к этому какая то сессионная информация храниться в localStorage. Боюсь надо очень внимательно отследить все, что передает браузер, посмотреть не шлет ли он дополнительно что то JS на странице... В общем я бы наверное не взялся бы за эмуляцию работы из браузера а сделал бы расширение для хрома которое бы дергало требуемую инфу и пересылало на свой сервер.

Comment: повторил все заголовки, которые посылает браузер. в ответ получил:  � �� C���    ни одна кодировка не подходит

Comment: Ну там кроме UTF8 ничего быть не может

Comment: @ВладимирНуров, если вы обратите внимание, то увидите, что в ответ на post-запрос в браузере ни чего не возвращается с сервера. Правда, одновременно с ним делается get-запрос. Но возможно нужный телефон зашифрован прямо в теле страницы и расшифровывается через javascript.